How to persist apt packages between container runs?
I have a CI/CD pipeline, I want to break it up into multiple steps:

Install dependencies (with apt)
Run script

I can set up volume mounts to persist across all containers, but I don't know which director(ies) need to persist. Right now I have the following directories:

/var/cache/apt/
/var/lib/apt/
/var/lib/dpkg/

But when the second step runs, the packages installed in the first are not available:

/tekton/scripts/script-1-kjxxf: line 13: git: command not found

I saw this question, but I don't want to have to create and manage a custom container, I'd rather just install the packages on the fly.
What other directories or configurations should I consider to get this working?

Since installing a package can create files pretty much anywhere except a few select locations like /tmp, /home, /usr/local, etc., if you won't run step 1, then you need to persist the entire filesystem. You can persist the package cache, but you still need to do the actual installation. TBH, I don't understand why you don't just create a custom container. Writing a Dockerfile isn't that hard, neither is rebuilding the image every so often to keep it up-to-date.
